# Jquery mobile, implement popup with numeric input, plus/minus buttons

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, input, popup

I am trying to create a popup dialog box where the user can input amount of x (numeric), with plus and minus button.

After long, unsuccessful, search for exist solution.

I use jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js.

---------  the code: ------------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).delegate('#inliner', 'click', function() {
        $('#inlinecontent').simpledialog2();
    });

    $(document).delegate('#amount_plus', 'click', function() {
        x = $('#prod_amount_input').val();
        x = eval(x)+1;
        $('#prod_amount_input').val(x);
        //$('#prod_amount_input').textinput('refresh');
        //$('#prod_amount_input_div').textinput('refresh');
        //$('#prod_amount_input').trigger('create');
        //$('#prod_amount_input_div').trigger('create');
        alert($('#prod_amount_input').val());

    });

    $(document).delegate('#amount_minus', 'click', function() {
        $('#inlinecontent').simpledialog2();
    });
</script>

<a href="#" id="inliner" data-role="button">Open Dialog #1</a>
<div id="inlinecontent" style="display:none" data-options='{"mode":"blank","headerText":"Amount","headerClose":false,"blankContent":true}'>
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a rel='' data-role='button' href='#' id="amount_plus">+</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c" id="prod_amount_input_div">
            <input type="number" name="number" id="prod_amount_input" value="0" >
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><a rel='' data-role='button' href='#' id="amount_minus">-</a></div>
    </div>
    <a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'>Close</a>
</div>
```

--------------- code end ---------------

if I use:

```
$('#prod_amount_input').textinput('refresh');
```

OR

```
$('#prod_amount_input_div').textinput('refresh');
```

the application go back to index.html page (from the page popup opened from).

if I use:

```
$('#prod_amount_input').trigger('create');
$('#prod_amount_input_div').trigger('create');
```

nothing happens.

from: `alert($('#prod_amount_input').val());` I know that the value is changed, 
but the value in the input field doesn't.

some ideas how to update the numeric input value in popup ?

what i try to create look like: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSCMm.jpg

thanks!